# Images are loading on simulater but not on Blackberry device

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator

I am using following code to download images from server

```java
public Bitmap connectServerForImage(String url) {

    HttpConnection httpConnection = null;
    DataOutputStream httpDataOutput = null;
    InputStream httpInput = null;
    int rc;

    Bitmap bitmp = null;
    try {
     httpConnection = (HttpConnection) Connector.open(url+ ConnectionType.getConnectionType());
      rc = httpConnection.getResponseCode();
     if (rc != HttpConnection.HTTP_OK) {
      throw new IOException("HTTP response code: " + rc);
     }
     httpInput = httpConnection.openInputStream();
     InputStream inp = httpInput;
     byte[] b = IOUtilities.streamToBytes(inp);
     EncodedImage hai = EncodedImage.createEncodedImage(b, 0, b.length);
     return hai.getBitmap();

    } catch (Exception ex) {
     System.out.println("URL Bitmap Error........" + ex.getMessage());
    } finally {
     try {
      if (httpInput != null)
       httpInput.close();
      if (httpDataOutput != null)
       httpDataOutput.close();
      if (httpConnection != null)
       httpConnection.close();
     } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();

     }
    }
    return bitmp;
   }
```

and ConnetionType class is as follows

```java
public class ConnectionType {

  public static String getConnectionType() 
  {        
        String connectionString = null;

        if (DeviceInfo.isSimulator()) 
        {
            connectionString = "";
            return connectionString;
        }         
        else if (WLANInfo.getWLANState() == WLANInfo.WLAN_STATE_CONNECTED) 
        {
            connectionString = ";interface=wifi";
            return connectionString;
        }         
        else if ((CoverageInfo.getCoverageStatus() & CoverageInfo.COVERAGE_DIRECT) == CoverageInfo.COVERAGE_DIRECT) 
        {
            String carrierUid = getCarrierBIBSUid();
            if (carrierUid == null) 
            {               
                connectionString = ";deviceside=true";
                return connectionString;
            } 
            else 
            {
                connectionString=carrierUid;
                return connectionString;

            }
        }           
        else if ((CoverageInfo.getCoverageStatus() & CoverageInfo.COVERAGE_MDS) == CoverageInfo.COVERAGE_MDS) 
        {
            connectionString = ";deviceside=false";
            return connectionString;
        }           
        else 
        {

            connectionString = ";deviceside=true";
            return connectionString;
        ]           

  }

 /**
  * Looks through the phone's service book for a carrier provided BIBS
  * network
  *
  * @return The UID used to connect to that network.
  */
 private static String getCarrierBIBSUid() 
 {

    ServiceRecord[] records = ServiceBook.getSB().getRecords();
    int currentRecord;
    for (currentRecord = 0; currentRecord < records.length; currentRecord++) 
    {
        if (records[currentRecord].getCid().toLowerCase().equals("ippp")) 
        {
            if (records[currentRecord].getName().toLowerCase().indexOf("bibs") >= 0) 
            {
                //otherwise, use the UID to construct a valid carrier BIB-S     
                String carrierUid= records[currentRecord].getUid();                                     
                String  extension = ";deviceside=false;connectionUID=" + carrierUid + ";ConnectionType=mds-public";                 
                return extension;                   
            }
        }           
    }
    for (currentRecord = 0; currentRecord < records.length; currentRecord++) 
    {
        if(records[currentRecord].getCid().toLowerCase().equals("wptcp"))
        {
            String carrierUid= records[currentRecord].getUid(); 
            String extension = ";ConnectionUID="+carrierUid;
            return extension;
        }
    }       
    return null;
 }       
}
```

Images are displaying fine on simulater but when I run this on my device No image displayed .Please suggest where I am missing.
Thanks!!!

Comment: Can you clarify what the failure is and where the failure is occurring?  I presume that it is timing out on this statement "rc = httpConnection.getResponseCode()", in which case you should review your getConnectionType() method and make sure it is providing the correct suffix.

Comment: @Peter :There is no failure in the code .The program run successfully on simulater and it displays the images .But when I run it on device then also program run successfully but at this time no image displayed. I think you are getting what is the problem.

Comment: check whether you getting the value of hai.getBitmap() or not.

Comment: @Signare: Yes I am getting the hai.getBitmap() .But it is displaying only on simulater and when I run this on device then no Bitmap displayed.

Comment: @DineshChandra. There is a failure in the code on device.  Guarantee it.  Yes the code is working on the Simulator, but on the Simulator getConnectionType() returns "" which is correct because you are running with the MDS Simulator.  Stop the MDS Simulator and try your code - I suspect you will see the same problem.  Then debug on the device to determine where in your code the processing is breaking.  Report back once you have this information.

Comment: Please include information with your question about which OS version is on your device **and** simulator.  Which model is your device **and** simulator?  Which kind of network connection are you using on your device **and** simulator (WiFi, BES, Direct TCP, etc.)?  You should *always* include this kind of information when code is working on one platform, and not on another.